# ¿Como agregar valor a un arreglo con espacios vacios (PHP)?

Tags: php

Tengo este arreglo:

```
   $datos = array(
                            "nombre" => array("Juan Perez","Pablo Manrique","Nancy Peña"),
                            "direccion" => array("Cra. 45 # 45 -56","Clle. 23 # 12 -19 Sur","Av. 34 # 16 -12"),
                            "telefono" => array("3456789","3214567","2135423"),
                            "fecha" => array("23/12/1997","12/10/1980"," 07/06/2000"),
                            "color" => array("Amarillo","Verde","Rojo"),
                            "significado" => array("Riqueza y alegría.","")
                        );
```

Como puedo validar que si significado tienes espacios vacíos les añada `"No se encuentra el significado."` al arreglo para después imprimirlo?

Esto es lo que he intentado ,pero no me funciona, ya que la idea es que `si color verde y rojo no tienen significado` debería de poner el mismo significado para ambos, pero no me funciona.

```
if(in_array("",$datos['significado']))
            {
                array_push($datos['significado'],"No se encuentra el significado.");
            }
```

Agradeceria el interes.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el arreglo completo por fa?

Comment: Hola buenas tarde puedes colocar el código completo de tu array.

Comment: claro ya lo pongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te entendí es que cuando tenga el valor de `""` lo remplace por `"No se encuentra el significado."` si es así puedes recorrer el arreglo y si encuentra uno que lo remplacé de esta forma:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($datos["significado"]) ; $i++) {
  if($datos["significado"][$i]==""){
    $datos["significado"][$i]="No se encuentra el significado.";
  }
}
```

Comment: Pff, excelente men, gracias .

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de dos formas en cuanto a la forma de ejecución:

1. Hacer un ciclo que recorrar el array y lo cambie :

```
    $datos = array(
                                "nombre" => array("Juan Perez","Pablo Manrique","Nancy Peña"),
                                "direccion" => array("Cra. 45 # 45 -56","Clle. 23 # 12 -19 Sur","Av. 34 # 16 -12"),
                                "telefono" => array("3456789","3214567","2135423"),
                                "fecha" => array("23/12/1997","12/10/1980"," 07/06/2000"),
                                "color" => array("Amarillo","Verde","Rojo"),
                                "significado" => array("Riqueza y alegría.","")
                            );

    for ($i=0;$i<count($datos["significado"]);++$i) {
            if ($datos["significado"][$i] == "") {
               $datos["significado"][$i] = "No se encuentra el significado.";
            }
        }


var_dump($datos["significado"]);
```

2. Una función para cuando lo vayas a pintar, que valide si es blanco lo asigne por defecto.

Saludos,